# How to change default Key-Entry behavior with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I've implemented the new version of TinyMCE successfully in a huge form, its works but there seems to be a bug whereby you can no longer hit return on another input text field to submit the form

For example, if you focus on a simple input text field, then hit the return key, instead of submitting the form, it opens the 'File' menu from the first WYSIWYG editor (with TinyMCE).

How do I change that ?

Thanks

Comment: well, tinymce version 4 is still beta - i recomment to report this to Moxiecode/the developers